# Remove trailing and leading white spaces around delimiter using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to remove white spaces from a string. However, I want to remove spaces around the delimiter and from beginning and ending of the string.

**Before:**

`" one two, three , four   ,five  six,seven "`

**After:**

`"one two,three,four,five six,seven"`

I've tried this pattern without success:
`/,\s+|\s$/g,","`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `/\s*,\s*/g`, and then `.trim()` the string.

Comment: @user2406718 Sorry, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Use the regex `^\s+|(,)\s+|\s+(?=,)|\s$` and replace matches with the first capturing group `$1`:

```js
var string = " one two, three , four ,five six,seven ";
console.log(string.replace(/^\s+|(,)\s+|\s+(?=,)|\s$/g, '$1'));
```

The capturing group is either empty or contains a comma when the regex engine encounters a space after a comma `(,)\s+` (for which we would better use lookbehind, but JavaScript does not support it).